# On using VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, vector

I am using `VectorPlot` to show direction fields for 1st-order differential equations.  I basically learned to do this by example (from Wolfram Documentation and examples here on SE).  But, I don't know why I am doing this so I need an explanation.

For example, I have a 1st order differential equation:
$$
y^{\prime} -\frac{2}{t}\,y = 4\,t
$$
So, my `VectorPlot` statement appears as:

```
VectorPlot[{1,-2y/t+4t},{t,-2,2},{y,-2,2},AspectRatio->1/2.5]
```

And, the resulting plot is shown below:
[image: vector plot]

Now my question.  The plotted values, per Wolfram documentation are $\{v_x,v_y\}$ or functions of x and y.  I figure that there is a reason that instead, in my example, I use $\{1,f[x,y]\}$ but I can only guess at the reasons.  Maybe something to do with parameterized equations but I am not that confident in that guess.  Can this be explained?  Also, I experimented with other values for $v_x$ instead of 1 such as $-2, -1, 0, 2, ... $ only to see a slight shift in the magnitude of some of the vectors but nothing else was obvious.  So, I really don't know what I am doing and help would be appreciated.

OK, I decided to guess and I would like confirmation on my guess.

Since I am plotting a direction field for a differential equation, I am plotting this function: $y^\prime = f(t,y)$.  Therefore, in using vector plot I am plotting a parameterized function $\{v_t,v_y\}$.  But, using differential notation, my parameterization is $\{t,f(t,y)\}$.  Since I am plotting derivatives though, the $t$ is actually $dt/dt$ which is 1.  Therefore, I am plotting the parameterization of $\{1,f(t,y)\}$.

Comment: A 2D vector field assigns a vector $(v_x,v_y)$ to each $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$. Which part do you have trouble with? You've got an ODE with only one dependent variable $y$, so obviously the $v_x$ component is the derivative of $t$ which is $1$.

Comment: @flinty  Thanks for the confirmation on my guess.